# Spring Security java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-hex character in input

Tags: java, windows, spring-security, character-encoding, tomcat7

I deployed an existing Maven project in my Tomcat Server on Windows7 environment. I'm using tomcat7 , spring-security-core 3.1.0 .

However, everytime I'm logging in my webapp, I received an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-hex character in input
```

The code is working perfectly fine in Linux environment. So I was thinking it's because I'm using windows7 in my local environment. When I look into the internet I saw that's it's a encoding issue between linux and windows.

I tried setting up

> **JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS** -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

but haven't succeeded. Please help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace for that exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, when you login, events happen is such order:

1. Spring selects an entity from DB by username.
2. Spring must check inputted password for match with stored encoded password.

To check for a match, Spring uses [PasswordEncoder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html), which you have most likely configured.

Your password encoder expects that stored encoded password is a hexidecimal char sequence (previously encoded by this PasswordEncoder). Thus, it tries to decode CharSequence into byte[], but fails ([source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/codec/Hex.java#L47)).

The solution is to persist users with previously encoded password, e.g. by BCryptPasswordEncoder.

Answer (score 0):

Answer Alex Derkach is right for me!
In my case i have DB with straight store password(develop) looks like User=roor, psw=root.
So when i comment(delete) `.passwordEncoder(new StandardPasswordEncoder("53c433t")); !` its work
!!But is wrong, password must be stored in encrypted form!!!

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for this is mixing password encoders. There're different implementations of [`PasswordEncoder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html). And, for example, if you use `SymmetricPasswordEncoder` for encoding and `StandardPasswordEncoder` for decoding you may get this exception.